# Finding most/least frequent elements with one loop

Tags: algorithms

This question could be trivial but I have tried to come up with an algorithm to list the most and least frequent elements in an array of int with just one loop, i.e `O(n)`.

`[1,2,1,1,3,3]`:

Most frequent: `[1,1,1]`
Least frequent: `[2]`

I'm aware that it's possible to do that with two loops. One to aggregate the count of each element and next to find the most / least frequent ones but I was wondering if I could do both in one loop.

Comment: Keep track of the most frequent element and count indexes while you construct the frequency array?

Comment: In the comparison model this requires time $\Omega(n \log n)$, by reduction from element distinctness.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks, could you give me an example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "example". The element distinctness problem asks whether all elements in an array are distinct. This is the same as asking whether the most frequent element appears more than once.